# Задача о прямолинейном движении с ускорением

Tags: c++, c++builder

Привет.

В общем, такая тема, делать надо на c++ builder. Задание такое.

> Функция F(t) задает закон изменения ускорений материальной точки при прямолинейном движении. Вывести на экран таблицу, в которой представлены значения времени (с постоянным шагом), ускорений, скоростей и перемещений. Продумать разделение программы на подпрограммы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lipsRollingMachine.h>

int formula(double v0, double t, double t0, double a)
{
    double V;
    V = v0 + (t - t0) * a;
    return V;
}

int main()
{
    int step;
    double V, v0, t, t0, a;
    cout << "Введите шаг";
    cin >> step;
    cout << "Введите начальную скорость, конечное время, начальное время, ускорение";
    cin >> v0 >> t >> t0 >> a;
    V = formula(double v0, double t, double t0, double a) lipsrolling(step, V);
    return 100500;
}
```

Comment: @Святослав1993, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Надо делать на билдере, а у вас консоль! Но если нужно в консоли, то 
выводите матрицу (та же таблица), где каждый столбец отвечает за определённую величину ,а строка = шаг.

Comment: А зачем include <губоЗакаточнаяМашина.h> ? :)

Comment: @insolor видимо кто-то уже помог автору с "его" кодом :)

Comment: @insolor, там функция lipsrolling

Comment: Я конечно снова посмеялся, но, ребята, тому комментарию, как и самому вопросу уже больше трех лет )

Answer (score 1):

Для прямолинейного движения. В цикле рассчитываются значения функции и выводятся на печать. То есть просто

```
for (int i == 0; i < STEPS; i++) {
    t = t0 + i * DELTA;
    s = s0 + t * SPEED;
    cout << t << "\t" << s << "\n";
}
```

Аналогично для других формул. Сам расчет формулы разумно вынести в функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Для равномерного движения можно использовать ответ [[@byte](/users/23/byte)](/users/23/byte), но для ускоренного движения уже нужно использовать методы численного интегрирования, например [метод трапеций](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_трапеций):

```
const dt = 0.001;

v = v0;
for(t=t0;t<=t1;t+=dt) {
    a = accel(t); // accel() - функция ускорения от времени
    cout << t << " " << s << " " << v << " " << a << endl;
    s += dt*(v + dt*a/2); // увеличиваем путь на площадь трапеции dt*(v+(v+dt*a))/2 = dt*(v + dt*a/2)
    v += dt*a; // по хорошему и тут нужен метод трапеций, но если ускорение изменяется медленно, то и так сойдет :)
}
```